# SSML in Action on Google-- prosody

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I was tweaking SSML in Actions on Google, thought I did it right, but the test app didn't change the rate and pitch in prosody(audio part was working fine):

```
   conv.close(`<speak>${conv.data.userName}.<prosody rate="x-fast" pitch="+5st">Can you hear me now?</prosody>, your lucky number is ` +
     `${luckyNumber}.<audio speed="200%" repeatCount="10" src="${audioSound}"></audio></speak>`);
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your SSML looks perfect. My experience with the [simulator](https://actions-console.corp.google.com/) has been that (maybe because of caching?) the simulator doesn't always immediately respond with updates when you update your webhook fulfillment.